# Why the elements cannot be add in this stack?

Tags: c, stack

I have this stack, and the elements of type NAMES(char), I'm trying to print all of the names of the array below (names) but I can't. Idk if the problem is in the STACK() function.

```
#define TAMMAX 30

typedef char NAMES[TAMMAX];

struct stack{
    int nItems;
    int capacity;
    NAMES *names;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;


bool stack(Stack *st, NAMES *name){

    if (st->capacity== st->nItems){
        return false;
    }

    strcpy(st->names[st->nItems], *name);

    st->nItems++;

    return true;

}

int main(){

Stack *st;

 NAMES *names[] = {
        {"James"},
        {"Kimberly"},
        {"John"},
    };

    int nNames= sizeof(names) / sizeof(Stack);

    for (int i = 0; i < nNames; i++){
        stack(st, names[i]);
    }

    printStack(st);

  return 0;
}
```

I have these warnings, I don't know how to fix them. The output of the code just print the first name of the array names: James.

```
stack.c:97:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
   97 |      {"James"},
      |         ^
stack.c:97:9: note: (near initialization for 'postagens[0]')
stack.c:97:10: warning: initialization of 'char (*)[50]' from incompatible pointer type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   97 |         {"Kimberly"},
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
stack.c:97:10: note: (near initialization for 'postagens[0]')
stack.c:98:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
   98 |         {"John"},
      |         ^
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, the value of `TAMMAX` is not shown. Also I would recommend against `typedef`:ing an array, it makes things confusing when you start talking about pointers to values of type `NAME`, at least to me. Further, `int nNames= sizeof(names) / sizeof(Stack);` makes no sense at all, the right hand side should be `sizeof *names`, and the value is `const size_t`.

Comment: This isn't even valid syntax, you're missing the `{` at the beginning of `main`

Comment: You declared `names` to be an array of pointers, but you're trying to initialize it with strings, not pointers to strings.

Comment: @Barman How can I fix that?

Comment: `NAMES namesp[]` instead of `NAMES *names[]`

Comment: @Barmar I  tried and  it had two warnings:  


warning: passing argument 2 of "Stack" from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  105 |         stack(st, NAMES[i]);
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                 |
      |                                 char *


stack.c:note: expected 'char (*)[50]' but argument is of type 'char *'
   44 | bool stack(Stack*str, NAMES *name){

Comment: `NAMES *name` should be `NAMES name` in the parameter list of `stack()`

Comment: You've already declared `NAMES` as a typedef to an array, you don't need `NAMES *` anywhere.